# How can I trigger onclick function when I press enter button?

Tags: javascript, html

I use the code below to update the url link based on user text input:

```
<input type="text" id="q" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" />

<script>
$(function () {
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var url = "/tag/";
    url += $("#q").val();
    window.location = url;
});
});
</script>
```

Right now it works pretty fine when someone clicks the submit button. What I want is to make it also work when a user press the enter button. [Fiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/keepitstupidsimple/bvX6Q/68/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
 if(e.which == 13) {
    var url = "/tag/";
    url += $('#q').val();
    window.location = url;
 }
});
```

Comment: Instead of repeating the code you can trigger the click handler: `$("#submit").click()`.

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work. Cant figure out what i am doing wrong :( Could you please check the Fiddle i provided above? Many thanks ! Keep in mind that i want to use both functions (Submit Button Click + Enter Press)

Comment: @Marsel try updated code

Comment: @jacob it works fine. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You might simply use `$(document).keypress()`
For this purpose extract your function out of `.click()` to avoid code replication like this:

```
<input type="text" id="q" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" />

<script>
$(function () {

var executeFunction = function(){
    var url = "/tag/";
    url += $("#q").val();
    window.location = url;
};

$("#submit").click(executeFunction);

$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13) {
        executeFunction();
    }
});
});
</script>
```

### Update

An even better solution would be the use of the jquery `.submit()` [event handler](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
<input type="text" id="q" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" />

<script>
$(function () {
$("#submit").submit(function() {
    var url = "/tag/";
    url += $("#q").val();
    window.location = url;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: @downvote could you give me a hint what is wrong with my answer? I'd gladly improve it...

Comment: well, upvote from me... and same question to downvoter.. don't get why our answers are not useful.